# laravel-vuejs: My vuejs component is not displaying

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

This question seem to have been asked a million times but none seem to solve my issue. I am new to vuejs, i have my laravel eCommerce website working appropriately, but i want to use a vue component as the "add to cart" button,

I renamed the exampleComponet.vue to addCart.vue, and i registered my component appropriately, yet, the button is not showing and am getting an error.

Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

i have tried several answers here which include clearing browser cache, registering component as `Vue.component(name: 'add-cart', require('./components/addCart.vue').default);` all didn't work

My addCart.vue:

```html
<template>
     <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" v-text="buttonText"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "btn",
        components: {

                    },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        props: ['tag'],

    }
</script>
```

app.js file:

````js
Vue.component('add-cart', require('./components/addCart.vue').default);```
````

My product.blade:

```html
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $product -> id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $product -> name }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="NewPrice" value="{{ $product -> NewPrice }}">
    <add-cart></add-cart>
</form>
```

I want to use the vuejs component with gloudemans/shoppingCArt to add and remove item from cart

Comment: It is good to name your components like ```export default {
  name: 'AddCart'
}```

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` to compile the javascript?

Comment: i did run npm run watch

Comment: Maybe also try refreshing your cache. Sometimes locally the JS can stick. Ctrl + F5 (windows/linux), cmd + shift + R (macOS). Also change the name of the component as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

change component name to 'add-cart' like:

```
export default {
    name: "add-cart",
}
```